# A question in proof of isomorphism of fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the following proof from the book : Basic concepts in Algebraic Topology by F.H Croom.( Page 66 of the book). I am not able to make this deduction so asking for help here.

Theorem(4.3) :If a space X is path connected and $x_0, x_1$ are points in X , then the
fundamental groups $\pi(X,x_0)$ and $\pi(X,x_1)$  are isomorphic.

Proof: Let $p: I \to X$ be a path such that $p(0)=x_0 $ and $p(1)=x_1$.
If $a$ is a loop based at $x_0$, then $(\overline{p} * a) * p$ is a loop based at $x_1$. Here $\overline{p}$ denotes the reverse of p:
$\overline{p}(t) = p(1 - t), 0 < t < 1$.

> Question: I am not able to deduce that $(\bar{p} * a) *p) $ is based at $x_1$ , given a is based at $x_0$.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Are you reading left-to-right?  $\overline{p}$ begins at $x_1$, and $p$ ends at $x_1$.  All is well.

Comment: $\bar{p}$ goes from $x_1$ to $x_0$, $a$ from $x_0$ to $x_0$, $p$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$. So in general the path is from $x_1$ to $x_1$.